# How do I include lodash in my protractor test specs?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I want to use lodash functions in my protractor spec, I'm using _.forEach() to fill a form with values.

How do I get lodash into my protractor script so that I can use it?

I'm not asking how to use it in my app, but in the actual running protractor scripts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the native Array.forEach(). If you need lodash do this:

Get the node dependency.

```
npm install lodash --save-dev
```

Then use it in your test.

```
var _ = require('lodash');

describe('foo', function() {
  it('should do stuff', function() {
    _.each();
  });
})
```

Comment: I'm glad you added the info about npm install.  I already had lodash installed with bower, but require('lodash') failed until I also installed it with npm.

Comment: @Mark0978 

Just to expand on your findings, bower is used to install front-end components while NPM is used to install node packages.   
   
Installing lodash with bower allows it to be used 'on-page in browser' (similar to how you'd use jQuery). Installing it with NPM allows it to be used by Node itself.

Comment: you have to add b browserify  as well . http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117092/jasmine-tests-in-karma-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined