# Karma Test Cases for CSS File Available or not in a folder or specific path

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I need to write test cases for css file so whether css file present or not on specific folder or path..So how to check using karma or jasmine test cases. Need help... Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this npm package: [file-exists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-exists) to check if filepath exists and is a file.

Comment: `describe('Testing CSS File Present or Not', function() {
   it('should be present or not', function(){
        const fileExists = require('file-exists');
        fileExists('../../source/css/solutionbuilder.css', (err, exists) => console.log(exists)) 
        //console.log(fileExists.sync('../../source/css/solutionbuilder.css')) //
        expect(fileExists.sync('../../source/css/solutionbuilder.css')).toEqual('True');
   });
});`
I wrote above test cases code but it will throw 'require' is not define.Please help me @Stanislav Kvitash in that

Comment: Take a look at the answers here: [jasmine tests in karma: Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117092/jasmine-tests-in-karma-uncaught-referenceerror-require-is-not-defined)

Answer (score 0):

You could implement basic node js inside the jasmine test case

```
var fs = require('fs');
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
// Do something
}
```